# Match by call name and parameters, for a call from other pallets

Tags: substrate, parity, polkadot

I have a module method that associates fixed fees to Calls from various pallets.
So I'm trying to match a Call passed to my method as a parameter by pallet, Call name, and Call parameters.

Something similar to this:

```rust
impl<T: Config> Module<T>
{
    fn compute_call_fee_(call: &<T as Config>::Call) -> Result<u64, &'static str> {
        let fee = match *call {
            Call::PalletA(palletA::Call::name_of_palletA_call(x,y)) => 50u64, // here this is not real syntax, this is what I need to figure out
            _ => 100u64
        };

        Ok(fee)
    }
}
```

for the case above the Config trait would implement the Config traits from the different pallets matched on:

```rust
pub trait Config: system::Config + palletA::Config + palletB::Config {
    type Call: Parameter + Dispatchable<Origin = Self::Origin> + GetDispatchInfo;
}
```

**How can I match on `call` by origin pallet, function name, and function arguments ?**

I've tried:

- using similar syntax as above, without success
- making the `Config::Call` implement `GetCallMetadata`: this only get me the origin pallet and function name, not the parameters
- making the call implement `IsSubType`, and following this answer: [How to decode and match a call when passed as a parameter in Substrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636775/how-to-decode-and-match-a-call-when-passed-as-a-parameter-in-substrate). This is not related to Calls from other pallets if I get it right.

  For using `IsSubType`, I've added it as a trait bound to the impl block rather than in the `Config` trait:

  ```rust
  impl<T: Config> Module<T>
  where
       <T as Config>::Call: IsSubType<Call<T>>, 
  {
      fn compute_call_fee_(call: &<T as Config>::Call) -> Result<u64, &'static str> {
          if let Some(local_call) = call.is_sub_type() {
              return match local_call {
                  palletA::Call::name_of_palletA_call(x,y) => Ok(42u64),
                  _ => Ok(0u64),
              }
          }
          Ok(21u64)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you paste your full code (reproducible, meaning the definition of `type Call` in your pallet) and the error that you get as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say until you paste your full code (specifically the `type Call = xxx` piece), but I can guess that what you miss is: `type Call: IsSubType<pallet_balances::Call<Self>>;`. You mentioned another question that recomended the same, but I can guess that you didn't use it correctly.

Note that overall, the outer `Call` (the one which you are passing into your pallet here via `type Call`) implements two things:

- `From<pallet_call>` for each individual pallet call. This will allow you to always convert an inner `Call` into an outer `Call`.
- `IsSubType<pallet_call>` for each individual pallet call. This will allow you to conditionally convert an outer call into an inner call, if it exists.

Perhaps the naming could have been a bit better here. I will consider at least renaming the outer `Call` to.. `OuterCall`.

Lastly, definitely recommend running a `cargo expand` on the node template and look for `enum Call`.

TLDR; this diff will work if you apply it on top of node-template, should answer your question as well.

```
diff --git a/bin/node-template/pallets/template/Cargo.toml b/bin/node-template/pallets/template/Cargo.toml
index 12b810de1..6f91e8c9a 100644
--- a/bin/node-template/pallets/template/Cargo.toml
+++ b/bin/node-template/pallets/template/Cargo.toml
@@ -25,6 +25,11 @@ default-features = false
 version = "2.0.0"
 path = "../../../../frame/system"
 
+[dependencies.pallet-balances]
+default-features = false
+version = "2.0.0"
+path = "../../../../frame/balances"
+
 [dev-dependencies.sp-core]
 default-features = false
 version = "2.0.0"
@@ -46,5 +51,6 @@ default = ['std']
 std = [
    'codec/std',
    'frame-support/std',
-   'frame-system/std'
+   'frame-system/std',
+   'pallet-balances/std'
 ]
diff --git a/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs b/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs
index 24de4f2f5..562675a0b 100644
--- a/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs
+++ b/bin/node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs
@@ -14,9 +14,11 @@ mod mock;
 mod tests;
 
 /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
-pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
+use frame_support::traits::IsSubType;
+pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_balances::Config {
    /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
    type Event: From<Event<Self>> + Into<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
+   type Call: IsSubType<pallet_balances::Call<Self>>;
 }
 
 // The pallet's runtime storage items.
diff --git a/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs b/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs
index 51df3dd5a..4ca2ab613 100644
--- a/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs
+++ b/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs
@@ -258,6 +258,7 @@ impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
 /// Configure the pallet template in pallets/template.
 impl template::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
+   type Call = Call;
 }
 
 // Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, using `IsSubType` was indeed the solution.

I needed to add it to the `type Call` associated to the `Config` trait, as @kiaenigma showed:

```rust
pub trait Config pub trait Config: system::Config + palletA::Config + palletB::Config {
    type Call: Parameter + Dispatchable<Origin = Self::Origin> + GetDispatchInfo + IsSubType<palletA::Call<Self>> + IsSubType<palletB::Call<Self>>;
}
```

Then in the Module's methods, slightly change my code to this:

```rust
impl<T: Config> Module<T>
{
    fn compute_call_fee_(call: &<T as Config>::Call) -> Result<u64, DispatchError> {
        match call.is_sub_type() {
            Some(palletA::Call::palletA_method1(_arg1,_arg2)) => return Ok(60_u64),
            Some(palletA::Call::palletA_method2(_arg1,_arg2,_arg3)) => return Ok(60_u64),
            _ => {}
        };
        match call.is_sub_type() {
            Some(palletB::Call::palletB_method1(_arg1)) => return Ok(40_u64),
            _ => {}
        };

        return 80_u64;
    }
}
```